# How to bring an image view in front of a button in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, button, kotlin, imageview

I want to put an image view in front of a button in Kotlin.
my problem is that the bringToFront method doesn't work.
I think it's because I have constraints attached between those two.

Here is my code:

XML file ->

```
//ImageView
<ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/stripe"
        android:id="@+id/stripe"

        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/playbutton" //<- could this be the reason for my problem?
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/playbutton"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"/>

//Button
<Button
        android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
        android:id="@+id/playbutton" 

        android:layout_width="80dp" 
        android:layout_height="80dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"



/>
```

Kotlin Activity file:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    stripe.bringToFront() //doesn`t bring stripe image view in front of play button

}
```

Comment: The `bringToFront()` method just rearranges the child `View`s in the parent `ViewGroup` so that the selected `View` is the last one in the parent's array of children. For `View`s that all draw on the same z-coordinate, that will cause the selected child to end up on top. However, `Button`s have default elevation that's greater than zero, and that's why that `Button` is still drawn above your `ImageView`. You'll have to adjust your `View`s' elevations, too, at least on Lollipop and above.

Comment: Thanks! That  solved my problem